# How does perf sample kernel stacks?

Tags: c++, perf

As far as I know perf is able to sample a full callstack for every process/thread even if it currently is inside the kernel. Since perf is running in userspace I assume, I want to know how it gets access to the kernel part of the stack of a different process/thread.

The purpose is to write an application that can sample callstacks of other processes/threads even if they currently are in kernel.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perf` consists of two parts. The userspace tools, and the `perf_event_open` syscall.

Generally, the stack sampling is done by the kernel through the syscall. You can write an application with also uses [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) - by default kernel samples are included (`exclude_kernel==0`).

Comment: According to the manual, I have to set parameters of a perf_event_attr structure, then open a file descriptor with perf_event_open, then keep reading from it via read. Say that my aim is to get the call stack of a hung process, which event types should I subscribe to and how would I parse the data from read?

Comment: You can read or you can `mmap`. For getting call stacks you set something like        `attr.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_IP | PERF_SAMPLE_TID | PERF_SAMPLE_TIME | PERF_SAMPLE_CPU | PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN`. You can use, for example, `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` // `PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES`.

Comment: And how many events will PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES generate? Every time the CPU does something? Would it be cheaper to sample process scheduling events?

Comment: The recording rate is decided by setting either `attr.sample_period` 
 or `attr.sample_freq` and `attr.freq` accordingly. The man page has all the details.

Comment: Note: This is quite a complex endeavor and I'm not able to put a full tutorial in the answer, but I'm happy to answer further specific questions.